# Avg. Response Time in Jmeter. Differentiate from Page Load time

Tags: jmeter

What is the meaning of "response time" in Jmeter?

Is the average response time equivalent to Page load time, or is it something different?

Answer (score 0):

As per [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) guide

> **RESPONSE TIME** is the amount of time the system takes to process a
>   request after it has received one. This parameter does not include
>   time that it needed to transmit HTTP/s requests over network to
>   web-server under test. 
>   **LATENCY** is the delay involved for your request
>   to reach the server.
>
> The response time that is required to receive a response from the
>   server is the sum of the **response time + latency**.

Response time is individual for each request and consists of server response time itself + time required for request to reach the server (latency)

Average response time is being **calculated** as arithmetical mean of all requests response times.

For instance, you have

- Request 1 - 4s
- Request 2 - 2s
- Request 3 - 5s

So Average Time would be (4 + 3 + 5) / 3 == 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" in the HTTP Request Sampler.

your Average Response time = Page Load Time

By Default "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" will be unchecked.

In order to measure the response time including the JS, CSS & Images (exactly as in the browser) this property should be checked before running the test.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
How do **you** define page load time?

JMeter will tell you exactly how long it took to **transfer over the network** all of elements you want to include as part of a "page load". This can include:

- Just the HTML page
- The HTML page and all embedded resources on the HTML page (images, css, js)
- The HTML page, all embedded resources and additional elements that are loaded after the initial HTML (such as elements that require Javascript / Ajax to load.)

What JMeter **won't** factor in is how long it took to execute any JS that ran on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the update. 

I have tried the same with steps below:
1. Add HTTP request default under Thread Group
2. Check the check box "Retrieve all embedded resources".
3. Record the script.
4. Verify the recorded thread.
5. Observe that in recorded thread  "Retrieve all embedded resources" is appearing unchecked.


Please confirm if this is not necessary in recorded thread. It would work fine when only check box is checked under HTTP request default.

Thanks in advance!